# What is the best utf8 collation in workbench for the data on many languages

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, mysql-workbench, multiple-languages

I'm developing a website([enter link description here](http://simmean.com)) to give simple,understandable meanings for the terms in different languages. I'm planning to add many languages as possible when the site grows. So the terms and some other stuff could be in any language and I need to create the database to do this without any issue.

I'm using mysql workbench to design the table schema.

It should be able to comapre the words in any languages when searches and also it should be as fast as possible on retrieving data

So what is the best choice to do that ? utf8-default or anything else ?

The Languages I'm focused up to now is:

1. Sinhala(Sinhalese)
2. English
3. Russian
4. Spanish
5. French
6. German
7. Chinese
8. Japanese
9. Danish
10. Tamil
11. Hindi
12. Italian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using multiple language on your database, I think `utf8_unicode_ci` might be the one for you.

**Accuracy**

- `utf8_unicode_ci` is based on the Unicode standard for sorting, and sorts accurately in a very wide range of languages.

**Performance**

- `utf8_unicode_ci` uses a much more complex comparison algorithm which aims for correct sorting according in a very wide range of languages. This makes it slower to sort and compare large numbers of fields.

Comment: Doesn't it affects on comparisons and arranging in asc order ? Can I use it for ordering too ?

Comment: OK I got it. Thanks Mike.